# Eclipselink generating wrong MySql LIMIT query when used with Composite Persistence Unit

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using `query.setFirstResult(startPosition);` and `query.setMaxResults(range);`. Lets say start position is 10 and range is 5. In the generated query, I'm getting LIMIT 10, 15. Shouldn't it be 10, 5?

Here is the code in my data access class.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public List<TableTwo> getTableTwoList(Integer start, Integer range) {
    LOG.info("-> getTableTwoList start={}, range={}", start, range);
    List<TableTwo> result;
    try {
        String queryStr = "SELECT t FROM " + TableTwo.class.getName() + " t ";
        LOG.info(queryStr);
        Query query = em.createQuery(queryStr);
        if (start != null) {
            query.setFirstResult(start);
        }
        if (range != null) {
            query.setMaxResults(range);
        }
        result = query.getResultList();
        LOG.info("<- getTableTwoList returning {} objects", result.size());
        return result;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        LOG.error("Got IllegalArgumentException ", ex);
        throw new RuntimeException("The criteria passed is incorrect", ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Got other Exception: {}", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Generic Exception occured", e);
    }
}
```

Also I'm using composite persistence unit. The persistence.xml files are given below.

Composite persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="CompositePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>
            org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
        </provider>
        <jar-file>../lib/modOne-1.0.0.jar</jar-file>
        <jar-file>../lib/modTwo-1.0.0.jar</jar-file>        
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.composite-unit" value="true" />         
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

First member persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="PUONE" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.test.poc.compositepu.entity.TableOne</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist"     value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update"  value="none" />
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT" />
            <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL" />
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Second member persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PUTWO" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.test.poc.compositepu.entity.TableTwo</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update" value="none"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Also I'm defining entity manager factory bean as follows

```
@Bean
protected EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws PersistenceException {
    LOG.info("-> entityManagerFactory");
    Map<String, String> props1 = new HashMap<>();
    props1.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_USER, DB_USERNAME);
    props1.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_PASSWORD, DB_PASSWORD);
    props1.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_DRIVER, JDBC_DRIVER);
    props1.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_URL, DB_HOST + DB_ONE + DB_PARAMS);
    Map<String, String> props2 = new HashMap<>();
    props2.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_USER, DB_USERNAME);
    props2.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_PASSWORD, DB_PASSWORD);
    props2.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_DRIVER, JDBC_DRIVER);
    props2.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_JDBC_URL, DB_HOST + DB_TWO + DB_PARAMS);

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> memberProps = new HashMap<>();
    memberProps.put(PU_ONE, props1);
    memberProps.put(PU_TWO, props2);
    Map props = new HashMap();
    props.put(ECLIPSELINK_COMPOSITE_UNIT_PROPERTIES, memberProps);

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(COMPOSITE_PU, props);

    LOG.info("<- entityManagerFactory emf.getProperties={}", emf.getProperties());
    return emf;
}
```

What am I missing?

**Update**:
The bug is reproduced in a small project and published in Github. 
https://github.com/thomasabraham/CompositePU

Eclipselink logs from the recreation is given below

```
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:30:35.842--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.parameters; value=true
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:35.862--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit CompositePU; session file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/_CompositePU; state Initial; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:30:35.864--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--property=eclipselink.orm.throw.exceptions; default value=true
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:35.891--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit PUTWO; session PUTWO; state Initial; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:30:35.892--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--property=eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-emf; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:30:35.894--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--property=eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache; default value=false
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2016-05-18 10:30:35.907--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/lib/modTwo-1.0.0.jar (There is no English translation for this message.)
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2016-05-18 10:30:35.911--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/lib/modTwo-1.0.0.jar (There is no English translation for this message.)
[EL Config]: metadata: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.098--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class[class com.test.poc.compositepu.entity.TableTwo] is set to [FIELD]. [EL Config]: metadata: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.136--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class com.test.poc.compositepu.entity.TableTwo] is being defaulted to: TableTwo. [EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.18--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit PUTWO; session PUTWO; state HalfPredeployedCompositeMember COMPOSITE_MEMBER_MIDDLE; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.181--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit PUONE; session PUONE; state Initial; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.183--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--property=eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-emf; default value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.184--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--property=eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache; default value=false
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.189--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/lib/modOne-1.0.0.jar (There is no English translation for this message.)
[EL Finer]: metadata: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.191--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Searching for default mapping file in file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/lib/modOne-1.0.0.jar (There is no English translation for this message.)
[EL Config]: metadata: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.196--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--The access type for the persistent class[class com.test.poc.compositepu.entity.TableOne] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: metadata: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.202--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class com.test.poc.compositepu.entity.TableOne] is being defaulted to: TableOne.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.206--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit PUONE; session PUONE; state HalfPredeployedCompositeMember COMPOSITE_MEMBER_MIDDLE; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.207--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit PUONE; session PUONE; state HalfPredeployedCompositeMember COMPOSITE_MEMBER_MIDDLE; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.213--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit PUONE; session PUONE; state HalfPredeployedCompositeMember COMPOSITE_MEMBER_FINAL; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.214--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit PUTWO; session PUTWO; state HalfPredeployedCompositeMember COMPOSITE_MEMBER_MIDDLE; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.216--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit PUTWO; session PUTWO; state HalfPredeployedCompositeMember COMPOSITE_MEMBER_FINAL; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.218--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit PUONE; session PUONE; state HalfPredeployedCompositeMember COMPOSITE_MEMBER_FINAL; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.224--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit PUONE; session PUONE; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.226--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit PUTWO; session PUTWO; state HalfPredeployedCompositeMember COMPOSITE_MEMBER_FINAL; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.228--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit PUTWO; session PUTWO; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.232--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit CompositePU; session file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/_CompositePU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finer]: weaver: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.237--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--JavaSECMPInitializer - transformer is null.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.237--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit CompositePU; session file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/_CompositePU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:30:36.239--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit CompositePU; session file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/_CompositePU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
May 18, 2016 10:30:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9080"]
May 18, 2016 10:30:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 18, 2016 10:30:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6766 ms
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.762--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Begin deploying Persistence Unit CompositePU;session file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/_CompositePU; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.764--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Begin deploying Persistence Unit PUONE; session PUONE; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.78--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--End deploying Persistence Unit PUONE; session PUONE; state HalfDeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.781--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Begin deploying Persistence Unit PUTWO; session PUTWO; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.782--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--End deploying Persistence Unit PUTWO; sessionPUTWO; state HalfDeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.785--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=FINEST
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.786--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.parameters; value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.786--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=FINEST
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.788--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.parameters; value=true
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.791--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Begin updateSession on composite memberPersistence Unit PUONE; state HalfDeployed
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.793--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=eclipselink.target-database; value=MySQL; translated value=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.803--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.user; value=root
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:45.805--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.password; value=xxxxxx
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.312--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.driver;value=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.313--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.url; value=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbone?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci& characterSetResults=utf8
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.318--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=eclipselink.cache.shared.default; value=false; translated value=false
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.322--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--End updateSession on composite member Persistence Unit PUONE; state HalfDeployed
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.323--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Begin updateSession on composite memberPersistence Unit PUTWO; state HalfDeployed
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.324--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=eclipselink.target-database; value=MySQL; translated value=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.328--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.user; value=root
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.331--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.password; value=xxxxxx
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.337--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.driver;value=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.339--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=javax.persistence.jdbc.url; value=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbtwo?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci& characterSetResults=utf8
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.341--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--property=eclipselink.cache.shared.default; value=false; translated value=false
[EL Finest]: properties: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.342--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--End updateSession on composite member Persistence Unit PUTWO; state HalfDeployed
[EL Info]: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.35--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services -2.5.1.v20130824-981335c
[EL Config]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.363--ServerSession(961795169)--Connection(717057583)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
        platform=>MySQLPlatform
        user name=> "root"
        datasource URL=> "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbtwo?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci& characterSetResults=utf8"
))
[EL Config]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.759--ServerSession(961795169)--Connection(1184531536)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbtwo?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci& characterSetResults=utf8
        User: root@localhost
        Database: MySQL  Version: 5.6.13
        Driver: MySQL Connector Java  Version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.26 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.761--ServerSession(961795169)--Connection(1184531536)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.762--ServerSession(961795169)--Connection(1184531536)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.766--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--PUTWO login successful
[EL Config]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.781--ServerSession(755784696)--Connection(976223442)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
        platform=>MySQLPlatform
        user name=> "root"
        datasource URL=> "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbone?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci& characterSetResults=utf8"
))
[EL Config]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.808--ServerSession(755784696)--Connection(1695019061)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbone?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci& characterSetResults=utf8
        User: root@localhost
        Database: MySQL  Version: 5.6.13
        Driver: MySQL Connector Java  Version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.26 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.81--ServerSession(755784696)--Connection(1695019061)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.811--ServerSession(755784696)--Connection(1695019061)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.814--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--PUONE login successful
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.844--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--sequencing connected, state is NoPreallocation_State
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.846--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--sequence SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY: preallocation size 1
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.848--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--sequencing connected, state is NoPreallocation_State
[EL Finest]: sequencing: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.849--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--sequence SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY: preallocation size 1
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.909--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/_CompositePU login successful
[EL Finer]: metamodel: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.932--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Canonical Metamodel class [com.test.poc.compositepu.entity.TableTwo_] not found during initialization.
[EL Finer]: metamodel: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.935--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Canonical Metamodel class [com.test.poc.compositepu.entity.TableOne_] not found during initialization.
[EL Finest]: jpa: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.936--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--End deploying Persistence Unit CompositePU; session file:/D:/Software/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/modThree-1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/_CompositePU; state Deployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finer]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.968--SessionBroker(1837692147)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--acquire client session broker
[EL Finer]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.974--ServerSession(961795169)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--client acquired: 1744273806
[EL Finer]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:46.974--ServerSession(755784696)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--client acquired: 2081015995
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.0--SessionBroker(585782081)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 1312157705
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.268--UnitOfWork(1312157705)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--begin unit of work flush
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.268--UnitOfWork(1312157705)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--end unit of work flush
[EL Finest]: query: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.269--UnitOfWork(1312157705)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Execute query ReportQuery(referenceClass=TableOne sql="SELECT Id, Name FROM TableOne")
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.276--ServerSession(755784696)--Connection(1695019061)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.277--ServerSession(755784696)--Connection(1695019061)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--SELECT Id AS a1, Name AS a2 FROM TableOne LIMIT ?, ?
            bind => [5, 15]
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.296--ServerSession(755784696)--Connection(1695019061)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.304--UnitOfWork(1312157705)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--begin unit of work commit
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.307--UnitOfWork(1312157705)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--end unit of work commit
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.308--UnitOfWork(1312157705)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--resume unit of work
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.309--UnitOfWork(1312157705)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--release unit of work
[EL Finer]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.311--SessionBroker(585782081)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--releasing client session broker
[EL Finer]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.314--ClientSession(1744273806)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--client released
[EL Finer]: connection: 2016-05-18 10:38:47.317--ClientSession(2081015995)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-9080-exec-3,5,main])--client released
```

Comment: What version of EclipseLink are you using, and what is the database platform class being used?  the MySQLPlatform class within EclipseLink has a computeMaxRowsForSQL method that should correct the max results from 15 back to 5, so check that it exists in the database platform class you are using and that it gets called for your query.

Comment: I'm using EclipseLink version 2.5.1-RC1. And I can see MySQLPlatform class, but I don't see the computeMaxRowsForSQL method getting executed. What could be the problem?

Comment: How are you creating and executing the query?

Comment: `Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryStr);`
`result = query.getResultList();`

Comment: Show the full code in context of the setMaxResults calls, the query string you are using etc - this works for others and test cases, so pseudo code doesn't really help show what might be going wrong for your usecase.

Comment: Can you turn EclipseLink logging to finest and show the query execution with parameter binding enabled?  computeMaxRowsForSQL  is called when the query addes the parameters as the translationRow to the query itself.  Do you have other special native hookins defined for these classes that might preset some of the queries and calls that would get used by this query? What happens if you add a parameter to this query?

Comment: @Chris Earlier I was not able to provide more info since I was working on a n extremely large code base. I have isolated the bug into a small project and published in github.

Comment: I updated the post with more details and logs.